# Formatting output in HBase

Tags: java, hbase

I want to get the rows of selected column family from HBase after applying Single Column value filter.

In my table 'Projectdata' I have column family like

```
    name|story|type|keyword

  aritra| kl  |ac  |happy
   nill |jk   |bc  |sad
   bob  |pk   |dd  |happy
```

. I want to get list of 'name'  when their 'keyword' is happy.
Here is my code.

```
public class ByCategory {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{

        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, "Projectdata");

        SingleColumnValueFilter filter_by_happycategory = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                Bytes.toBytes("keyword" ),
                Bytes.toBytes(""),
                CompareOp.EQUAL,
                Bytes.toBytes("happy")
                );
        FilterList filterListk =new FilterList();
        filterListk.addFilter(filter_by_happycategory);

        Scan scanh = new Scan();
        scanh.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("name"));
        scanh.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("keyword"));
        scanh.setFilter(filterListk);


        ResultScanner scannerh = table.getScanner(scanh);
        String key = new String("~");
        String keyFlag = new String("~");
        System.out.println("Scanning table... ");

            for(Result resulth: scannerh){
                //System.out.println("getRow:"+Bytes.toString(resulth.getRow()));
                 key = "~";
                for(KeyValue kv:resulth.raw())
                {
                    if(key.compareTo(keyFlag)==0){
                        key=Bytes.toString(kv.getRow());
                        System.out.print("Key: "+key);
                    }
                    System.out.print(Bytes.toString(kv.getValue()));

                }
                System.out.println("");

            }
            scannerh.close();
            System.out.println("complete");  
            table.close();
        }

    }
```

I am geting output like this

```
Key: 102happybob
Key: 109happyaritra
```

But I want to get only name. I am trying to get

```
 Key: 102bob
 Key: 109aritra
```

Is it possible in hbase? Where is my fault actually?

Comment: Your question is messy and unclear. you say 'where in 'name' column i have values like {aritra,nill,bob,jakob} and in 'keyword' column {happy,sad,emotional}etc' and also do 'scanh.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("name"));'.So are these columnfamily or column?

Comment: sorry.I have edited my question. All of these are column family.

Comment: Still unclear,how can a columnfamily have values without a column name?Is it the rowkey or the column name?Removed earlier answer,will answer once question is clear.

Comment: I have updated my question. Here column family i have no qualifier. That's why in Single Column value filter I have to keep column qualifier field blank.Here cf is acting like column

Comment: try in hbase shell
_put 'Projectdata','50','name:','kumar'_
I think this will make you clear how there are values in cf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for(Result resulth: scannerh){
        System.out.println("Key: "+Bytes.toString(resulth.getRow())+Bytes.toString(resulth.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes(""))));
    }
```

You will get the desired output.Here `resulth.getRow()` gives you `rowkey` while `.getValue(columnfamily,column)` gives you value of a specific column which is `""` in your case.